# webrtc and dropzone.js, on iOs Safari when a guest try to upload the camera will transmit black screen, how it comes?

Tags: webrtc, dropzone

I have my site to make video-calls based on WebRTC. I added the feature that allows guests to upload files during the video-call using dropzone.js.
In iOs Safari, in the moment that I click to browse and upload, the camera stop to work and the guest on the other part starts to see black screen, and a reload of the page is needed to make it work again. Infact, in top of the phone of sender, the camera icon disappears and is replaced only by mic icon.
How to solve it?
thank you.

Comment: I too get the same issue! Did you come across any solution? @alessandro